# How to compute the max supported frame rate for the camera for given resolution

Tags: android, android-camera

According to this doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setCaptureRate%28double%29:

> "For resolutions that can be captured by the video camera, the fastest
>   fps can be computed using getPreviewFpsRange(int[])"

but I cannot find any example about it.

I've tried to:

```
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    p.setPreviewSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
    cam.setParameters(p);
```

i.e. setting preview size with all kind of resolutions but calling `getPreviewFpsRange(int[])` after that always returns the same result like 5000 - 30000 on Nexus 4, or 5000 - 60000 on acer tablet. Does that mean that these devices support the maximum fps for all resolutions or am I missing something?

Does someone know how to compute the max fps per resolution?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, this method should return a fixed value - a range with fixed MIN and MAX. When you fix the resolution, the FPS also becomes fixed (ideally, though in reality it fluctuates a bit. But, still it is close to a fixed value). So, changing the resolution does not change the MIN/MAX value for this device and camera.

Comment: I was expecting that when I set higher resolution fps range will have lower upper bound...

Answer (score 0):

getSupportedPreviewSizes is now [deprecated along with Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html). However, [in AOSP](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/hardware/Camera.java#Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29) it only ever returned a fixed list of frame rate ranges that were independent of the resolution. Some manufacturers might have overridden this behaviour, but I have never seen it, and it would be undefined in how it related to a particular preview resolution.

On at least one device I get 30 FPS for preview resolution 1280 x 720 and 15 FPS for everything else, including low resolutions such as 320 x 240. I suspect that the graphics drivers are optimised for particular preview resolutions, but the old Camera SDK has no way to share this information even if the driver makes it available.

The Camera2 interface appears to offer a solution in the form of [getHighSpeedVideoFpsRangesFor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getHighSpeedVideoFpsRangesFor(android.util.Size)), but I haven't tried it myself.